# Is there a way to restore/format an iPod under Linux?

Tags: multimedia, ipod, format

I have an iPod Classic, and it's full of duplicates and it's a complete mess and would like to start anew, and I was curious if there was a way to restore an iPod like you could under Windows/Mac?

Answer (score 2):

While Banshee and amaroK offer the possibilty to load songs onto the iPod there is, as far as I know, no option to restore or format these things.

However: The iPod Touch has a restore function in the settings menu and I think my iPod classic had one of those too. I can't check anymore though, since it's been broken for some time.

If it's really just about getting rid of the duplicate songs you could just delete those with any of the mentioned linux programs.

Comment: nice =)! btw welcome

Answer (score 2):

It seems this was answered in [this Ubuntu forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1263715).

I'm going try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Banshee media player, it **might** be able to do what you are looking for. Optionally you could install itunes using playonlinux (it's in the software center).

Answer (score 0):

While I do not believe there is an option to format or *F-Disk* your iPod so to speak you can delete all the songs etc off of it using Banshee or Rhythmbox. Also, your iPod should have a *Reset* option in it's settings menu but I'm not so sure as to that or not. But you should be able to erase all the song data off of it using Banshee :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to restore my iPod under linux:

First, install Windows7 32bit under virtualbox and install iTunes and launch it. Then, put your iPod on recovery mode (turn off your iPod first, then press and hold the home button before plugging in the USB connected to your computer. Don't let go of the home button until you see the recovery screen.) Then, iTunes will automatically detect the device and restore it.