# Resetting an Apple ipod shuffle

Tags: ipod, apple

I am trying to use my Apple ipod shuffle with linux and i can't transfer the music from the pc to the ipod. The ipod always has to be reset using windows. Is there anyway to reset it using Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I understand Apple works with Apple stuff. No other "fruits" allowed. :) The only way that would work is Wine+iTunes, but it seems like it doesn't work [anymore](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=762278). Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10387/is-there-a-way-to-restore-format-an-ipod-under-linux) if you need more info.